Workable area pixel range of monitor (without bezels)
I know the EDID information received from monitors gives you the native resolution for that monitor (usually the highest supported resolution). The native resolution for a monitor should be the physical number of pixels on the display screen of the monitor. Eg 1920x1080 resolution means 1920 pixels x 1080 pixels.
I want the workable pixel count of a monitor, ie the pixels which are not part of the bezels, on which you can render images. Are bezels part of the pixel count as described by the resolution?

The resolution reported by EDID only refers to the actual workable and usable area.
anything outside is unknown and technically cannot be known or looked up.
someone might even disassemble their screen and use their panel bare-bone, in which case you still can't be sure, as each panel has different paddings to each side based on construction.
the workable pixel count of a monitor is always x by y as reported by the recommended EDID setting.
so for a 1920x1080 screen, 2073600 pixels in total with sub-pixel as well as sub-pixel arrangement varying depending on panel type.
